# linking problem when calling main.c in compilation unit

Tags: c, linker

Suppose that we call main.c in another c file in the compilation unit.
I understand that this is illegal since we can only call header file. However, why does it cause a bad linking but not a bad compiling when we make build everything?

The C file that calls main should be something like this:

```
#include "main.c"

int add (int x, int y) { return x+y; }
}
```

Comment: You cannot "call" either a header file or a .c file.  You can call functions that are defined in various translation units.

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to include C-files.  Header files should be included, but files that contain function definitions (eg, `.c` files) should not be.  Are you using the word "call" to mean "include"?

Comment: I think the answer is: it depends on how you are building things.  The example you show could be used to successfully build an executable, or it could cause a link problem.  But it depends on how you attempt to build.

Comment: Please format your code properly. But it's wrong anyway, it cannot compile, there is a stray `}` at the end.  Please post a [mcve].  Also we don't know what `main.c` is and how you compile your code.

Comment: It's not "illegal". You can `#include` any file, it simply substitutes the contents of that file in place of the `#include` line. But it's not usually the right way to combine `.c` files. That's normally done by compiling them separately and then linking the object files together.

Comment: It is not "illegal" to `#include` one .c file in another.  It is widely considered poor practice, but the language does not forbid it.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to determine why you have a link error. My crystal ball is hazy today, but it seems to be showing me a duplicate definition of `main()` error, arising from compiling and trying to link together both main.c and another file that `#include`s main.c.  But the ball has been on the fritz lately, so I'm not sure how reliable that is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to `#include` C files, but there is nothing strictly illegal about it.  The `#include` directive effectively copies the source code directly into the current file.  What you currently have can be made to work:

```
$ cat main.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int, int);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int a = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;
        int b = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) : 1;
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, add(a, b));
        return 0;
}
$ cat add.c

#include "main.c"

int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
$ cc add.c
$ ./a.out
1 + 1 = 2
$ ./a.out 3 -5
3 + -5 = -2
```

If you are getting linkage problems, it is probably because you are trying to do something like:

```
$ cc main.c add.c
```

Which is problematic since you now have duplicate definitions of `main`

Possibly what you want to do is to remove the `#include` from the `add.c` and do something like:

```
$ cat add1.c
int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
$ cc -c add1.c
$ cc main.c add1.o
```